# SUGARCRM - after installation only home page (dashlets) and Reports module are blank

Tags: installation, sugarcrm

I have version  6.5.10 installed on  Ubuntu 12.04.

After installation when I login my home page is blank (without dash-lets only shortcuts to module) and I can go to each module except for Reports module which opens me completely blank page?

What can be the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you

this is from error log

```
[Thu Mar 07 16:20:00 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.122] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 516171 bytes) in /var/www/crmpro/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crmpro/index.php?module=Calendar&action=index
[Thu Mar 07 17:08:19 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.122] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 516171 bytes) in /var/www/crmpro/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crmpro/index.php?module=Calendar&action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:40:29 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 594552 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:40:39 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 600349 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:41:02 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /var/www/crm/modules/Users/authentication/SugarAuthenticate/SugarAuthenticate.php on line 350, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Home&action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:41:22 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 574099 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login&login_language=en_UK
[Thu Mar 07 21:41:46 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /var/www/crm/modules/Users/authentication/SugarAuthenticate/SugarAuthenticate.php on line 350, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Home&action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:42:12 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 578184 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login&login_language=sr_RS
[Thu Mar 07 21:42:45 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /var/www/crm/modules/Users/authentication/SugarAuthenticate/SugarAuthenticate.php on line 350, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Home&action=index
[Thu Mar 07 21:44:45 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 596391 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/index.php?module=Users&action=Login
[Fri Mar 08 00:01:48 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 08 00:01:49 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 08 00:04:04 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 08 00:04:05 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 08 00:04:37 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 08 00:04:56 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 08 00:05:13 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 596370 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488
[Fri Mar 08 00:05:39 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 414782 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/
[Fri Mar 08 00:05:47 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 412645 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crm/
[Fri Mar 08 00:05:47 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 08 00:06:22 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 604665 bytes) in /var/www/crm/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488
[Fri Mar 08 00:10:22 2013] [error] [client 192.168.254.26] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 136314880 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 695686 bytes) in /var/www/crmpro/include/nusoap/nusoap.php on line 8488, referer: http://192.168.0.202/crmpro/index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index
```

this is from /proc/meminfo memory info

```
root@crmdemo:/var/log/apache2# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        1019080 kB
MemFree:          477272 kB
Buffers:            7752 kB
Cached:            91496 kB
SwapCached:        29236 kB
Active:           137384 kB
Inactive:         254092 kB
Active(anon):      97864 kB
Inactive(anon):   196360 kB
Active(file):      39520 kB
Inactive(file):    57732 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
```

Comment: This sounds like it is the result of a PHP fatal error.  You will need to check your PHP error log to see if there are any fatal errors listed.  If there are, you can post the lines with the error messages to give us more information.  I'd guess that you are hitting a memory limit issue (which is very common on brand new installations), or there is some configuration option that is wrong.  But I'd need to see the PHP error log to confirm.

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. Do you mean to give you /var/www/crm/sugarcrm.log file? I will update my question with it

Comment: or what other log you meant (location of the file will be helpful?) thank you

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu for this, the log file should be located here:  `/var/log/apache2/error.log`  The log file may be very, very large, too big to post in its entirety, so you'd need to look for lines that start with "PHP Fatal".

Comment: I updated can you take a look?

Comment: I think you were right it's says some memory problems- but why and how to solve this?

Comment: I updated also with memory info for the current environment when I run application

Comment: I change memory limit parameter in php.ini and now it works!!! thank you Kyle. Best regards

Comment: Thanks; I'll post an "Answer" and you can accept it.

Comment: No problem. You gave me the right inputs. That was my first installation so haven't on mind that memory limit. If you have time just give me some solution for web service response for my previous problem. Sorry for your time really but can't find some good guide how to process my request and response through the Sugar. But OK whenever and if you have time. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the logs that you have posted, it looks like the PHP memory limit is the issue.

SugarCRM is very memory hungry, so increasing the default PHP memory limit on most servers will be required.  Usually 128 MB or higher (I use 256 on my installations) will be needed.

You can increase your default PHP memory limit by editing your `php.ini` file in the root of your SugarCRM installation, or by editing the default server `php.ini` file in `/etc/php5/apache2/`.